# XML in string type Variable issue Php

Tags: php, arrays, xml, string

Please view the below code

```
$xml_string = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <res:ResultMsg xmlns:res='http://cps.huawei.com/cpsinterface/result'>
            <![CDATA[
            <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><Result><ResultParameters><ResultParameter><Key>FailedReason</Key><Value>The value 611015125123 of the CNIC parameter is incorrect, failed to authenticate the parameter.</Value></ResultParameter></ResultParameters><ResultCode>2002</ResultCode><ResultType>0</ResultType><OriginatorConversationID>20180904165750</OriginatorConversationID><ResultDesc>Transaction information is invalid.</ResultDesc><TransactionID>000000000000</TransactionID><ConversationID>AG_20180904_00007be9004e56992e5f</ConversationID></Result>]]>
</res:ResultMsg>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";
```

Then I get the type of Variable

```
$type=gettype($xml_string);
```

echo string alright.
When I Try to echo the actual Value, it just print out a part of it.

```
FailedReasonThe value 611015125123 of the CNIC parameter is incorrect, failed to authenticate the parameter.2002020180904165750Transaction information is invalid.000000000000AG_20180904_00007be9004e56992e5f]]>
```

Why is this strange behavior happening. I tried replacing all the new line characters as well, but it didn't help. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: "_When I Try to echo the actual Value_" In a browser? View the source and see if it's all there. Or output it between a `<textarea></textarea>`. Or use `CLI` to print it out

Answer (score 1):

Stupid mistake at my end, Answering in case someone stumbles upon this issue.As per the comment to my question all I had full data but it, wasn't shown by browser because of tags.

```
 echo "<textarea>";
           echo $manual ;     
 echo "</textarea>";
```

did the job.

Comment: Other ways to output the XML raw: `echo htmlspecialchars($manual);` to escape the `<`, `>`, and `&` characters; or, `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` to tell the browser not to parse *any* HTML on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$regex = '#<Value>(.*?)</Value>#';
$code = preg_match($regex, $xml_string, $matches);

echo $matches[0];
```

You can try this way. It's not an xml parse, it's more of a php/regex approach but will do the work for you.

The output is : *The value 611015125123 of the CNIC parameter is incorrect, failed to authenticate the parameter.*

I also run on the same problem as you did with parsing this soap-xml response so i thought of this work around that works. After all it's a string type and php has really nice tools to parse strings using regex.